# How can I locate the defadvice for an advised function in Emacs?

Tags: emacs, elisp, advising-functions, defadvice

When I view documentation for `beginning-of-defun`, there is a note:

```
This function is advised.

Around-advice `senator':
Move backward to the beginning of a defun.
If semantic tags are available, use them to navigate.
```

However I can't find in which .el file the defadvice is called. Is there any way to navigate to the original file, where the advice is defined?

**Edit:** While i marked correct Phils' suggestion to rgrep the .el files, i still hope, that there is some more elegant way to trace back to the defadvice.

Comment: I agree. It seems something of an anomaly that you cannot locate these kinds of definitions automatically.

Comment: The discussion on this topic continued in [another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17539241), where eventually I've stumbled over a trick that could provide this information with less effort / more consistently. Leaving this comment for future googlers here :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know there is no way to navigate to the location of a `defadvice` expression (I'd be delighted to be proved wrong).

This should presumably track it down:

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `rgrep` <kbd>RET</kbd> `(defadvice 'beginning-of-defun` <kbd>RET</kbd> `*.el` <kbd>RET</kbd> `~/.emacs.d/` <kbd>RET</kbd>

(or failing that, the site-lisp directory would be the next place to look)

You can also view the advice data structure like this (but this doesn't include the information you're looking for).

```el
(ad-get-advice-info 'beginning-of-defun)
```