# How to debug a defadvice

Tags: emacs

How can you go about debugging an error with a defadvice involved?

Searching for solutions all I can find is recommendations not to use defadvice because of the debugging difficulties. Amen to that, but other peoples defadvices are everywhere and I'm always running into bugs I can't even begin to track down.

Comment: Finding where the defadvice is is my very first road block and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967367/how-can-i-locate-the-defadvice-for-an-advised-function-in-emacs) suggests an obvious command doesn't exist.

Comment: You could put a breakpoint in the `ad-defactivate` the very first thing you load Emacs and then wait for your advice to trigger it and work from there... That's a lot of troubles, but if you only need to do it once...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One more thing I could think of:

1. Temporary rename `defadvice` into `defadvice-old`.
2. Write this new version of `defadvice`:

---

```
(defmacro defadvice (function args &rest body)
  `(progn
     (put ',(cadr args) 'source-position
          (cons byte-compile-current-file byte-compile-read-position))
     (defadvice-old ,function ,args ,@body)))
```

1. Examine the `(symbol-plist <<name of advice>>)` once you need it, it would have the position in the file of the file that used the macro.

Comment: Oh, that's very clever. You should cross-post the idea in that other Q&A.

Comment: Thanks,, excellent hack.  This idea should make it into emacs as defadvice-defadvice.

Comment: @phils I know that some people who work on the Emacs own sources are regulars on SO. Perhaps some of them will step in / maybe there's some pitfalls on having `defadice` remembering the advice position. If not - this looks worth of feature request. I'd maybe send one then.

Comment: @tonyday or `defadice-rec` :P whichever dialect you prefer.

Answer (score 3):

One option is to make the advice body call a function to do its work, and then you can debug the function instead.

Note that you can evaluate `(ad-deactivate 'function)` to deactivate all advice for the specified `function` (this will revert the function to its unadvised state). This might help if some advice is causing you serious problems while you are trying to track it down.